# Problema com paths do typescript

Tags: typescript, path, eslint

Olá,

estou usando a configuração do eslint do airbnb e ela está dando um erro no paths do typescript.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Olá, seja bem-vindo ao StackOverflow em Português. :) Por favor, **[edite](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/478263/edit)** a sua pergunta para remover o código em imagem em favor de código (e mensagens de erro) em texto. Conforme você pode ler [aqui](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5483/manual-de-como-n%c3%83o-fazer-perguntas/5485#5485), postar códigos como imagem não é recomendado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

De acordo com a documentação do *plugin* `eslint-plugin-import`, a regra [`import/no-unresolved`](https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import/blob/master/docs/rules/no-unresolved.md):

> Ensures an imported module can be resolved to a module on the local filesystem, as defined by standard Node require.resolve behavior.

Em tradução livre:

Garante que um módulo importado possa ser resolvido para um módulo no sistema de arquivos local, conforme definido pelo comportamento padrão de `require.resolve` do Node.js.

No entanto, como você está utilizando essa TypeScript, o uso dessa regra do ESLint é redundante, já que o TypeScript (além de realizar análise da tipagem do código) por padrão verifica se os módulos que você importa realmente existem e são válidos.

Portanto, utilizando TypeSript, você pode seguramente desativar essa regra.

```
// .eslintrc.json
{
  "rules": {
    "import/no-unresolved": "off"
  }
}
```

Comment: Fico muito agradecido por sua ajuda e tempo!